# my site crawler died while it's running

Tags: php, web-crawler

I wrote a site crawler to get links and images to create site map but it killed while running! so it's not my whole class

```
class pageCrawler {

    .......

    private $links = array();

    public function __construct ( $url ) {

    ignore_user_abort ( true );
    set_time_limit ( 0 );
    register_shutdown_function ( array ( $this, 'callRegisteredShutdown' ) );
    $this->host = $urlParts [ 'host' ];
    $this->crawlingUrl ( $url );
    $this->doCrawlLinks ();

}
```

---

`$this->crawlingUrl ( $url )`: 
at beginning main address set to this method (e.g http://www.mysite.com)
`getUrl()`: connect to url by fsockopen then get url contents
`findLinks()`: return `a href` and `img src` and then store returns links in `$this->links[]` then i echo something to flush output and insert following code after that :

```
echo str_pad ( " ", 5000 );
flush ();
```

---

`$this->doCrawlLinks()`: 
it's check `$this->links` and do same process that i describe in top for first element of `$this->links`
then shift first element 
again `doCrawlLinks()` run and get url content of first element then shift first element of `$this->links` till `$this->links` get empty

---

it's general trend of my class it's work but suddenly it's crashed suddenly. i set `set_time_limit(0)` to do forever but my process dosent't finish because my shoutdoown function dosent execute ! i confused where is my problem

Comment: Do you have your error reporting turned on? error_reporting(E_ALL); in case it times out because of an error at the rest of your script?

Comment: "connect to url by fsockopen" - OMG! why?????

Comment: @symcbean : i used CURL but ihave this problem again

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess - do you have a recursion in doCrawlLinks() ? Deep recursion can simply crash process. Or it can crash by memory limit per process.

From my experience, it is very helpfull to keep the list of links in database with pending/processed flag on them, so you can shutdown and resume your crawler any time you want (or in your case - resume it after crash).

Comment: i thought memory limit it's my problem but sometimes in 3 or 4 recursion it got crashed !:(